# how to get new line in xslt which will displayed in text as well as html format on blackbary handset?

Tags: xslt, blackberry

Below is my xslt format -

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ms="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
      <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="CallXML">
      Added by Vinserve do not delete this line. %$ <xsl:value-of select="sCallID"/> $%

      Dear <xsl:value-of select="sMailTo"/> ,

      <xsl:text>

    </xsl:text>

      <xsl:value-of select="sCommentBy"/>  added a comment to call made by  <xsl:value-of select="sCallOwner"/>.
        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>

      Comments:   On( <xsl:value-of select="sCommentDate"/>)
        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
        --------------------------------------------------------
        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>

        <xsl:value-of select="sComment"/>
        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>

    Original Call Details
    <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>
        ----------------------
        <xsl:text>
    </xsl:text>


  <xsl:value-of select="sCallSub"/> , <xsl:value-of select="sCallDate"/> , <xsl:value-of select="sCallType"/> , <xsl:value-of select="sCallOption"/>
    <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>

    Party:  <xsl:value-of select="sPrimaryParty"/>
            <xsl:text>
        </xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
             </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

i have used `<xsl:text></xsl:text>` tag for new line character. I don't want to use `<br>` or any `html tags for new line character`. My output will be seen in html or text format.
I even tried to use `&#10` and such other characters for new line. but it did not give me any results. I am not understanding the exact problem that why i am not getting the new line. Could anyone please help me with this?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add a line break to the XSLT output, it is usually best to use `<xsl:text>` with a character entity: `<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>` But this won't "work" for HTML documents even though it does output a newline to the source.

HTML specification defines that all whitespace should be collapsed. This means that all newlines and tab characters are converted to a space character and all subsequent spaces are converted to one space. How this is done, depends on the HTML viewer application. Therefore, in HTML, the only way to show a forced line break to user is to use `<br>` element. However, `<br>` is not a general line break symbol for all XML languages so `<br>` will be shown as a line break only in (X)HTML documents.

Comment: +1 You may need two transforms, one for TEXT output and one for HTML output. You could also put the text inside of `<pre>` (preformatted text) or a `<textarea>` in order to display the text and preserve the line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:

```
<xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
```

or

```
<xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
```

HTML tags won't work if your output method is `text`, while the entities swhon above (or `xsl:text`) should.

Comment: I want to show my xslt generated output in both text as well as html format on the blackbary hadset browser. But i don't want to use any html tags in my generated output. And i used above tages but it is not working on both situation.